# Inheritance tree in android programming

Tags: java, android, class, inheritance

I have been introduced to android programming recently and it is a new experience for me.

Well I was looking for some graphical representations of inheritance classes in android. Below is a simple example for an `ImageButon` and `Button`. Any source like that would help me/us in a  better understanding of the concepts and relations between classes.

[image: tree]

Comment: I am not sure that a graphical representation would satisfy you. After a while due to the large number of classes you would be unable to make any sense of it. Why do you need it? You can get which class implement which class etc isn't that enough?

Comment: @Eypros yeah that might be true but still the most used and important classed wouldn't be a bad idea to have them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Eclipse the Type Hierachy View might help you. You can open it from the context menu or by pressing F4 when a class selected. If you do this on the parent class (in your example `View`), you see the inheriting classes in a tree. If you start way down in the hierachy you could switch to "Supertype Hierachy" with the buttons on top of the view to see all implemented interfaces.

This way you can navigate through the class hierachy and try to understand it. This might be a little more suitable than having the whole diagram, which, as Eypros pointed out, could be very complex and not very clear.